# metadata rejected Schedule 2, section 3.8(b)

Tags: ios, app-store

today my app is rejected due to

### ------

Guideline 3.1.2 - Business - Payments - Subscriptions

We noticed that your app did not fully meet the terms and conditions for auto-renewing subscriptions, as specified in Schedule 2, section 3.8(b) of the Paid Applications agreement.

App Store Information
We were unable to find all of the required information within your metadata.

We were unable to find a link to your Terms of Use in either the app description or the License Agreement section of App Store Connect.

### -------

As according to the description I guess the apple wants me to put a "Terms of Use" link in description

1) Is not "Terms of Use" is same as tearms and condition
2) I get to know apple rejects because we didn't provide the auto-renewing  information, but I ahve added all the information about the weakely and yearly subscription and their renew information in app description.

please let mme know what I need to do hear

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't App Store support

Comment: @jonrsharpe this is an issue for me, I need some help to solve this out, please help